# How to show my number when calling out?

Tags: calls, 7.0-nougat, asus-zenfone-3

I have my SIM card set to block the number I'm calling from when calling out. I need this due to work.

What is annoying is that some contacts I need to get a hold of will usually not pick up "Unknown numbers" that call, requiring me to leave a message. I know if I turn my Call ID back on, they pick up right away. **I understand this behaviour, and I do it as well**.

My issue is that on my phone, I have to go through 5 menus before my number is unblocked, then back to the main Phone screen, then make the call, then back to those 5 screens to turn the blocking back on.

I know I can block *per call*, but then I need to remember to turn this on. Is there an easy way I can quickly enable/disable the Call Block setting? I'm on an Asus ZenFone 3 on the Telus network (purchased through 3rd party supplier, not from Telus directly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put *31# before the number you're calling.

More information: [Enabling Caller ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID#Enabling).

> Depending on the operator and country, there are a number of prefix
>   codes that can unblock Caller ID.
>
> - Australia: 1832 (landline and mobile phones)
> - Czech Republic: *31* (landline)
> - Denmark: *31*
> - Germany: *31# (Some mobile providers)
> - India: *31#
> - Ireland: *31# (dialling from mobile) 142 (dialling from landlines)
> - Japan: 186
> - Hong Kong: 1357
> - New Zealand: 0196 (Telecom/Spark)
> - North America: *82 (*UB, UnBlock), 1182 (rotary phone)
> - Switzerland: #31#
> - United Kingdom: 1470
>
> On GSM mobile networks, callers may dial ***31#** before the number
>   they wish to call to enable caller ID.

Comment: Perfect! Worked when calling my work phone! Thanks!

Comment: I bet you could edit your friend's phone number so it is *31# 123457 etc. so they are always unblocked.